# sprintf function's arguments and formats in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'v read and re-read the help about the function **sprintf** in matlab but I do not understand everything about this function and the *format* they talk about.

I was asking myself the logic behind the function formats.

If I run the example

```
sprintf('%05d%s%02d%s%02d',546,'.',1,'.',3)
```

I get

```
00546.01.03
```

which is logic, since the first number (546) is written as an integer and with 5 digits, the second is a character, and so on... But if now I try this

```
sprintf('%05d%s%02d%s%02d',546,'.',1,'.',3,4)
```

I get

```
00546.01.0300004
```

the first part is the same as above... But the last part of it (00004) has the format '%05d', that corresponds to the first format I entered in the function's arguments. My question is then *Does the first format become the 'default' format ?*

By trying this

```
sprintf('%05d%s%02d%s%02d',546,'.',1,'.',3,4,56)
```

and getting this

```
00546.01.03000048
```

I think the answer is *no*... But why ? And **what is then the logic behind those arguments?**

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Or could it be that it forms a sort of loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing `sprintf` more arguments than there are `%`s in the format string. Therefore, `sprintf` re-uses the format string from begining:

```
sprintf('%05d%s%02d%s%02d',546,'.',1,'.',3,4,56)
```

result:

```
00546.01.03000048
```

> ```
>          ^  
>          starting fromat anew printing 00004 for %05d with 4
> ```

The final '8' character is 56 printed as `'%s'` (if you want to check it out the [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of '8' (the char) is 56!)